# Drupal 7 sends emails with out attachments

Tags: php, javascript, email, drupal, email-attachments

I have a problem with sending mail with attachment in Drupal 7.

I tried usual module,  I tried mimemail, I tried Zend Framework (or something like that)... but it just doesn't work. I get an email with a message, but it doesn't contain attachment.

here is my code:

```
function my_form_submit() {
if(!empty($_POST['body'])) {
$postbody = $_POST['body'];
$userpost = $_POST['usermail'];


  $attachment = array(
  'filecontent' => file_get_contents('sites/default/files/test.txt'),
  'filename' => 'test.txt',
  'filemime' => 'text/plain',
  );


 $body = '  <html>
               <body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" >
               <span style="width:100%;float:left">
               <img style="width:20%; float:left" src="cid:logo" alt="" />
               <div style="width:80%; float:left">
               </div></span>
               <span style="width:100%; float:left">'.$_POST['body'].'</span>
               </body></html>';

        $my_module = 'mime';
        $my_mail_token = 'notice';


  $message = array(
   'to' => '"'.addslashes(mime_header_encode('Request')) .'"<'.$_POST['mail'].'>',
   'subject' => t('[Hinnaparing]'),
   'body' => $body,
   'headers' => array(
   'From' => 'noreply@test.com',
   'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
   'Content-Type' => 'text/html;charset=utf-8',
   'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => '8Bit',
      'X-Mailer' => 'Drupal',
   ),
        );
       $message['headers']['CC'] = '<'.$_POST['usermail'].'>';
      $message['params']['attachments'][] = $attachment;

          $system = drupal_mail_system($my_module, $my_mail_token);
        if ($system->mail($message)) {
          // Success.
        }
        else {
   // Failure.
  }
}
}
```

I installed SwiftMailer drupal module, and now he is sending attachment but without Body and Subject of mail. What should I do to send them?

```
function my_form_submit() {
if(!empty($_POST['body'])) {
$postbody = $_POST['body'];
$userpost = $_POST['usermail'];
$ourpost = $_POST['mail'];



 $body = '  <html>
               <body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" >
               <span style="width:100%;float:left">
               <img style="width:20%; float:left" src="cid:logo" alt="" />
               <div style="width:80%; float:left">
               <h1>Hinnaparing № '.$file.'</h1>
               </div></span>
               <span style="width:100%; float:left">'.$_POST['body'].'</span>
               </body></html>';


  //File two (not managed by Drupal).
  $fileone = new stdClass();
  $fileone->uri = 'sites/default/files/034.jpg';
  $fileone->filename = 'drupal_logo.jpg';
  $fileone->filemime = 'image/jpeg';

  // Add attachments.
  $p['files'][] = $fileone;

  // Send e-mail.
  drupal_mail('modulename', 'key',$userpost, language_default(), $p,'noreply@test.com');
 drupal_mail('modulename', 'key',$ourpost, language_default(), $p,'noreply@test.com');



}
}
```

Comment: Come on, use **more** Drupal code.

Comment: Sorry, I am not Drupal master, so maybe you will help to improve my code?

Comment: You have installed and enabled the Drupal mime mail module, right?

Comment: Yes, I tried it..but it didn't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some cursory googling reveals it's thorny at best.

Try this class:

https://github.com/gollyg/Attachment-Email

(via: http://www.metachunk.com/blog/sending-e-mails-attachments-drupal-7)

Or use SwiftMailer:

http://swiftmailer.org

I'm unsure if the latter will be part of Drupal 8, but it will at least be [compatible](http://www.davetech.com/blog/drupal-8-symfony-2).

Comment: this class didn't work for me, but i installed SwiftMailer with drupal module(https://drupal.org/project/swiftmailer). It's sending attachment now, but without Subject and Body, you can see my edits..

Comment: I'm honestly not familiar enough with Drupal or its SwiftMailer module to be of much more assistance. But FWIW, it doesn't look like you're setting the `$subject` or `$body`.

Comment: yes, I realise it:)... this is the problem, I can't find a place where the Subject and body should be set..

Answer (score 0):

I can't see that you've implemented the [hook_mail](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail/7)? This is where you would usually set the subject and body of an e-mail. This is also described in the [Swift Mailer documentation](https://drupal.org/node/1590190).